# How can I automate Redis Perl library installation for icinga?

Tags: perl, redis, automation, chef-infra, cpan

I want  to automate the redis perl library using chef . I am using [Nagios-check](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/check_redis-2Epl/details) for the insatllation , but the problem is while installing you are prompted for answers to various questions. How can I automate this process. The commands I am using manually while installing are :

```
> cpan (prompts for questions)
(cpan shell opens)
> make install
> install Bundle::CPAN
> install Redis
>exit
```

Basically I am looking for all these steps to automate, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `cpan` in non-interactive mode:

```
execute 'cpan -i Redis' do
  only_if 'cpan -D Redis | grep -e 'Installed:$'
end
```

Or something like that (double check the guard command, that's just off the top of my head). Or better yet, use the community cookbook (https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/perl) which has a custom resource for this.